# get directory from full path

Tags: c#, directory

If i have:

C:\temp\foo\bar\

(**NOTE:** bar is a directory)

how can i parse out:

**bar**

Comment: Is the bar a file name or another directory?

Comment: bar is a directory . . i have added another \ to make it explicit

Comment: Sandman - i definitely could parse this out manually but wanted to see  if there was a more elegant solution.  I dont see why you should spentd 30 minutes searching if you can push this question out on SOF.  Now, next time someone has this question, they will find it right away  on google via search

Comment: leora, i support your approach, since you have just saved me 15 minutes of parsing a string. i am that someone how posted the question on google and got an answer strait away, saving me time. thanks for your simple but helpful question.

Comment: @Sandman This is not the first time that a arrogant user tells someone to "just google it" and the first result is that very post.

Comment: I agree with the last 3 comments, the comment that makes my blood boil the most is "just google it", in some cases some people may have already done so with no helpful result.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory_);
string currentDirectoryName = info.Name;
```

Answer (score 21):

Try

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\\temp\\foo\\bar");
```

Answer (score 11):

Just use:

```
string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\foo\bar\").Name;
```

According to MSDN this returns the name of the directory, not the full path.

[Link to MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx)

Hope this helps.........

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a bunch of people have withdrawn their answers, which is possibly a shame.

This one's got to be worth stating, only for the "teach a man to fish" quality of it - it's short, elegant and made of two separate things that, once learned, can be re-applied to other problems.

```
string lastPiece = wholePath.Split('\\').Last();
```

`Last` will throw if the list is empty.

Comment: maybe it's better to use (System.IO) PathSeparator ?

Comment: Where do you get the `Last` method ? Linq ? But it wont throw an exception because split results have a size of at least 1 item.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do this **without** creating a new **DirectoryInfo** instance is to use the ***Path.GetFileName*** static method.  This is located in System.IO.

```
using System.IO;

string lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Folder1\Folder2");
```

The variable would be set to "Folder2".

This is **quite a bit more efficient** that creating a new instance of the DirectoryInfo class!

Comment: You are correct - the last backslash causes that, that I had in the example.. otherwise.. as advertised.

Comment: to avoid the case where the last backslash might return an empty string i am using Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Folder1\Folder2"); since it will return Folder2 in both the above case and the Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Folder1\Folder2\"); case. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of 4 ways instantly

## 1

- If the string ends with a slash remove it
- Use Path.GetFilename (or numerous other System.IO methods)

## 2

- Split the string on slashes into an array
- Get the last index of the array

## 3

- Create a Uri class with it in the constructor
- Use the Segments property

## 4

- The linq way someone mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

```
string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;  
Console.WriteLine(dirname);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unix this is known as the basename, a quick google came up with this [link for a C# version](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_23106486.html). I'm sure there are others ...

Answer (score 0):

if the answers above do not satisfy your needs, why not just substring the string from the last .

```
string dirName = originalDirName.Substring(originalDirName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

sure, you should do some checking if the originalDirName does not end on a \ and if the originalDirName is longer than zero and actually contains \ characters.

Comment: Good call. More efficient than splitting if it's just the last dir in the path that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string DirName = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(@"C:\temp\foo\bar\").Name;
```

Comment: has to check for `\\` at the end otherwise returns foo