# Get specific folders path from a full way with Path class ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following full path:

`D:\Test1\Test1_1\Test2_1\Test3_1\Test4_1`

If I call

`Path.GetFileName(abovePath)` will return `Test4_1`

[get directory from full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670819/get-directory-from-full-path)

Well.

I want to get `Test2_1\Test3_1`, for example.

How to do that with `Path` class if is possible ? If not, how to proceed ?

I want a generic example, do not focus only my given full path.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DirectoryInfo and Parent, e.g.

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(abovePath);
var parentDirectoryName = directoryInfo.Parent.Name;
var grandParentDirectoryName = directoryInfo.Parent.Parent.Name;
```

Note you would want null checks on these but that's the general idea